# Calendar Primefaces perdendo estilo com ajax update

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, calendar

O component calendar do primefaces está perdendo o estilo após fazer o update com ajax na view. O que eu faço pra resolver?

Answer (score 0):

Solução para vencer o bug ao fazer update usando ajax no componente calendar na view (.xhtml), neste caso o meu calendar "dataRetorno" estava sendo afetado.

**OBS: ESTOU UTILIZANDO, DE FORMA MOBILE, O PRIMEFACES 5.3** !!!!

Na view, foi necessário inserir dois atributos abaixo no componente calendar "dataRetorno".

- style="border-width: 0px;"
- styleClass="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset"

Além disso, inseri na minha bean um trecho código em um evento de outro campo relacionado com o calendar "dataRetorno".

No meu método changeEventCampoQtdDiasVendidos(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) { }

```
    /*trecho do código para resolver o bug do update */
    org.primefaces.component.calendar.Calendar calendarDataRetorno = (org.primefaces.component.calendar.Calendar) FacesContext
            .getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot()
            .findComponent("formCadastro:dataRetorno");
    calendarDataRetorno.setStyle("border-width: 1;");
```

Comment: Você tentou usar o update="?" apontando somente para um calendar?

Comment: No meu caso eu usei  update="inputText1 inputText2 calendar", mas o erro acontece colocando só o calendar também.